# how to get next li active and set its css?

Tags: jquery

I have the following html....

```
<ul id="navs">
    <li class="activenav">one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

css...

```
.activenav{
    background-color: red;
}
```

jquery....

```
//$(window).load(function(){
    var $curli = $('#navs .activenav');
setInterval(function(){
    $('#navs .activenav').removeClass('activenav');
    $curli.next().addClass('activenav');

}, 2000); 
$curli = $('#navs .activenav');
//});
```

Key problem is that it is functioning for first time only. I need to set background-color of next from current li that is `.activenav`. And also I need to do this in load function but currently I have commented that even outside load function is also not working.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mh5gk/)

Comment: You need to set `$curli` inside the function. You're just setting it twice (to the same thing) when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var $navlis = $('#navs li')

setInterval(function(){
    var $next = $navlis.filter('.activenav').removeClass('activenav').next();
    if(!$next.length){
        $next = $navlis.first();
    }
    console.log($next)
    $next.addClass('activenav');

}, 2000);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CGsze/)

Comment: I think console.log($next) is not placed in right place for if condition

Comment: Please delete all comments as these are unnecessary for future users.

Answer (score 0):

This will handle even if the current `active` element is last element of list.

```
   var ul = $('#navs');
   function switchActive(){
        var li =  ul.find('.activenav'), next;
        if(li.is(':last')){
           next = ul.find('li:first');
        }else{
           next = li.next();
        }
        li.removeClass('activenav');
        next.addClass('activenav');
   }
   switchActive();
```

`switchActive` need to be called each time to switch next. Here is the sameple http://jsfiddle.net/W4p3P/

Comment: @C-Link It requires minimum sense before commenting like this. Check here it is working http://jsfiddle.net/W4p3P/

Comment: I don't know why in your answer it was not working and in your comment I see working..

Comment: In my answer I have called method only once, and you are supposed to call that method using setInterval after delay.

Answer (score 0):

See **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/NjyML/1/)**

```
setInterval(function () {
    var $curli = $('#navs .activenav');
    var $next = $curli.next();
    $curli.removeClass('activenav');
    if (!$next.length) {
        $('#navs li').first().addClass('activenav');
    } else {
        $next.addClass('activenav');
    }
    ind++;
}, 1000);
$curli = $('#navs .activenav');
```